# Sort objects based on the creation date of their children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, forum

I am creating a basic forum in rails. I have a Forum that has many Threads, and the Threads have many Posts. I want to get all the Threads for a particular forum and order them in such a way that the first one is the Thread that has had the latest Post.

In my Post's repository I have a method that will return the latest post.

```
 def latest_post
    order('created_at DESC').limit(1).first
 end
```

In the Threads class I have a method call latest_post that returns the latest post

```
 def latest_post
    self.posts.latest_post
 end
```

I use that method in the following way in order to get the latest post for a thread.

```
@some_thread.posts.latest_post
```

Now I want to get the ordered list of threads. I tried to add a default scope to the Thread class in order to order them by default.

```
default_scope order('latest_post.created_at DESC')
```

This did not work. I believe due to the fact that the latest_post part of the ordering is not at a database level.

How can I order the Threads based on the creation date of their latest post. It does not need to be a default ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative answer:

I added a last_post_at column to the Thread table. When a new post is created it updates this value.

I was then able to set the default scope ordering.

```
 default_scope order('last_post_at DESC')
```

**Advantage:** Do not need to load all the posts when creating the ordered list of Threads for a forum.
**Disadvantage:** Maintaining another column on the Thread model.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 scope :latest_post_first , Thread.joins(:posts). # joins needed to access posts for each thread
                            # grouping enables the SQL MAX function 
                            # also returns unique threads
                            group("threads.id"). 
                            # order by maximum value of post's created_at in each group 
                            # i.e. each thread since grouping is by thread id
                            order("MAX(posts.created_at) DESC")
```

Note that this would only return thread's with at least one post so I do not recommend to make it the default scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exactly the solution I was looking for. My only concern is efficiency. If the Thread has a lot of posts, would this method begin to degrade in speed?

Comment: sql inner joins would slow down with number of post rows it needs to retrieve, in that case caching or another column is a better option.